# Using multiple same dropdown id but the second dropdown onwards does not trigger onchange events

Tags: javascript

**View**

```
//first dropdown
<select id="dropdown_change" type="first_dropdown">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>

//second dropdown
<select id="dropdown_change" type="second_dropdown">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$("#dropdown_change").change(function() {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    alert(type);
});
```

When I try to select the first dropdown, the alert() works fine but the problem is, the second dropdown does not trigger the alert(). These 2 dropdowns are at the same view. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because an id value can be given to only one HTML element, in other words, multiple elements cannot have the same id value on the same page.
class value can be given to one or more HTML elements, usually of the same type.

Try below code

**View**

```
//first dropdown
<select class="dropdown_change" type="first_dropdown">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>

//second dropdown
<select class="dropdown_change" type="second_dropdown">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(".dropdown_change").change(function() {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    alert(type);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` show be unique to only 1 element in a page. Try adding a `class` to both `dropdown` then it should work.

```js
$(".dropdown").change(function() {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    alert(type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//first dropdown
<select id="dropdown_change" class="dropdown" type="first_dropdown">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>

//second dropdown
<select id="dropdown_change" class="dropdown" type="second_dropdown">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in a document. If you have multiple elements with same [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), that [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) will always refer to the first matched element in the document. Try [*class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead:

```js
$(".dropdown_change").change(function() {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    alert(type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dropdown_change" type="first_dropdown">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown_change" type="second_dropdown">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I love data-* Attributes (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

```js
    $(".dropdown").change(function() {
        var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
        alert(type);
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select class="dropdown" data-type="first">
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>
    <select class="dropdown" data-type="second">
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>
```